# Loading JSON file with plain JavaScript, no framework, no jQuery

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get my head over JSON file, to load and access properties with native js and display them on html.

This is my JSON file/

```
      {
      "London": [
        {
          "Manchester": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "isFurnished": true,
              "price": "1300",
              "hasBalcony": true,
              "bedRooms": 2,
              "type": "Long term",
              "features": {
                "security": "Secure Gated Parking",
                "access": "Close To Schools & Doctors"
              }
            },
  {
              "id": 2,
              "isFurnished": true,
              "price": "1300",
              "hasBalcony": true,
              "bedRooms": 2,
              "type": "Long term",
              "features": {
                "security": "Secure Gated Parking",
                "access": "Close To Schools & Doctors"
              }
            },
            "Manchester Area",
            [
              {
                "id": "Manchester Science Park",
                "isFurnished": false,
                "price": "739",
                "hasBalcony": false,
                "bedRooms": 1,
                "type": "Moderate term",
                "features": {
                  "fun": "On-site cafe",
                  "parking": "Options for car parking",
                  "meeting": "Free informal meeting space"
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "Manchester Science Park",
                "isFurnished": false,
                "price": "739",
                "hasBalcony": false,
                "bedRooms": 1,
                "type": "Moderate term",
                "features": {
                  "fun": "On-site cafe",
                  "parking": "Options for car parking",
                  "meeting": "Free informal meeting space"
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "Manchester Science Park",
                "isFurnished": false,
                "price": "739",
                "hasBalcony": false,
                "bedRooms": 1,
                "type": "Moderate term",
                "features": {
                  "fun": "On-site cafe",
                  "parking": "Options for car parking",
                  "meeting": "Free informal meeting space"
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Okey, here is my JSON. As you can see, i want to build real estate for me and to have some project as a portfolio.

For example when page loads, I want to show every listing for specific city. For example. In my JSON i have Manchester, but i will have more cities. So, page loads and every city is shown Manchester, LOndon, Chelsea etc.
So when item Manchester is clicked, to display every object under Manchester array.

How the hell to do that?

Comment: Will you be hosting this json in a separate file on your web server?

Comment: For now, it will  on ,my local machine. This json file is inside js folder.

Comment: Will reading the json in to a javascript object be fine?

Comment: Shall we assume you're asking about browser JavaScript (rather than e.g. Node) and whey you say "file" you actually mean AJAX? What exact problem do you have? Your description appears to refer about looping nested objects :-?

Comment: No node here, just local json file, i want to load  with javascript and display in html. My Problem is that, i don't know how to load  local json file with js

Comment: Then I'm positively sure that it's just not possible. Browsers are not designed to manipulate files in the local file system. If I recall correctly there were some past attempts (Internet Explorer and its proprietary ActiveX/VBScript technologies) but they were never cross-browser and were eventually abandoned. There's also HTML5's [FileReader web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) but as far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong) it can only handle files that are previously selected by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example I make use of ajax to read a `json` file and return it as a Javascript object. `XMLHTTPrequest` will go out and grab our `json` file reading it as plain text and our `JSON.parse()` method will turn the `json` in to a javascript object. From there you can do with the data as you please.

```
    function getJsonObject(cb){
            // read text from URL location
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', 'js/yourjson.json', true);
            request.send(null);
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                    var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

                           try {
                             cb(JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                           }catch(err) {
                             cb(err);
                           }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now to access the jsonObject you are trying to reach invoke function by passing a `callback function` that takes the object as an argument in to the `getJsonObject` function.

```
getJsonObject(function(object){
     //Do what you want with the object here
     console.log(object);
});
```

Comment: Or you could use FileReader() :)

Comment: You should wrap `JSON.parse` in a `try/catch` block, since it will throw if the JSON is invalid and in a callback, that error might be silently dropped.

Comment: @ssube Good Idea!

Comment: @ssube I added the `try/catch` per your suggestion.

Comment: Awesome! The `return` from within `onreadystatechange` won't leave `getJsonObject`, though, which it looks like you're relying on (you can't just `return` from a callback). You probably want to use `getJsonObject(cb)` and pass the value instead of returning: `cb(JSON.parse(...))`

Comment: @DominicValenciana I made a small edit so this will run correctly, feel free to roll back and/or revise if I was mistaken.

Comment: t@ssube I reviewed the changes and like them very much. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this, could you give me example of how to access JSON now?

Comment: @Bokchee88 I edited the post to include your request.

Comment: This answer doesn't comply with the question specs, which specifically talk about local files.